# perl - strings comparison and regex

Tags: regex, string, perl

What is the difference between the two lines?

```
if ($data =~ m/$str/) {
       ####  ^--- HERE
    print "OK"; 
}
```

and

```
if ($data =~ /$str/) {
    print "OK"; 
}
```

The whole difference is just an 'm'.

Comment: Still waiting for the punchline.

Comment: they both work the same. The question is "what is the added value of the m?". Why most examples use m/ /, while just / / makes the job?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html from a google search for `perl if m`

Comment: I know this page. It doesn't explain anything about // (without m). If m/ / compares regular expressions, how is it possible that this comparison is done even without writing the 'm'?

Comment: This is a good question for a beginner. I know many beginners who are confused by this and wonder if there is a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m` is indicator that you're about to use matching regexp, as opposed to replacing, using transliteration or other operators that can be used with `/`. If you use `/` as separator, then `m` is optional. Standalone `/` assumes `m`. `m` is mandatory if you want to use other symbols as quotes around regexp like `$str =~ m|$regexp|`. This is useful for writing more readable code if you regexp contains lots of `/` inside so you don't have to quote them.

Additionally, some other separators that can be specified with `m` will process quoted string differently.
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators

> With the m you can use any pair of non-whitespace (ASCII) characters
>   as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names
>   that contain "/", to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome). If "?" is
>   the delimiter, then a match-only-once rule applies, described in
>   m?PATTERN? below. If "'" (single quote) is the delimiter, no
>   interpolation is performed on the PATTERN. When using a character
>   valid in an identifier, whitespace is required after the m.